# SharePoint: how to know web service's host SPSite's url

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a web service hosted under a SPSite, whose url is http://server/sites/blank/_layouts/_vti_bin/service.asmx.

In a web service method, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url looks like http://server/_vti_bin/service.asmx/Method, which makes sense, as IIS doesn't know anything about SPSite's.

But, SPContext.Current is null :-(

How can I know the url where service is being hosted? Am I missing something that instantiates SPContext.Current for ex. during deployment of the service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Man, I just use SPContext.Current.Web.Url .

SPContext.Current is null at the WebService? 
I think it's not working in the context of a sharepoint site. Just using the url the IIS structure.

Hope this link help you : [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. That's where I'm going... which specific steps of those outlined in that page are the ones that tell SharePoint to host the web service? I may be missing that, but as far as I can tell, based on how I created the service and deploying, I followed what the link describes. Thanks again.